# iPhone headset with 4pin stereo doesn't work with computer through adapter

Tags: audio, microphone, headset

I have a headset compatible with iPhone/iPad/iOS.

I bought the adapter DEXP 3.5 mm Jack (F) - 2 x 3.5 Jack (M).

And the mic doesn't work. Phones is ok.

When I connect a simple headset with two jacks (green and pink) then it works.

OS: Windows 10 Pro

MotherBoard: ASUS P8P67PRO.

I already tried to update audio drivers (Realtek). Result is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Apple uses a proprietary [TRRS](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)) connector. Your adapter most likely does match this standard.  You will need to replace the adapter with one that specifically supports the Apple TRRS connector.

Comment: It works at my work PC. Same headset, same adapter. And doesn't work at home. I think that this is connected with motherboard, probably.